# Winform User Control on ASP?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I wrote a C# Winform User Control as follows when Executable is Run:

[image]

My question is how we can use this Winform C# user control in one ASP Page. I know about WEB User Control and using in ASP but what about using WinForm User Control that design in C#?

Comment: You can't. They're different UI's, different classes, different namespaces... You can't. You might as well be asking how you use your Android UI code for iOS.

Comment: [I guess it is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225666/hosting-windows-form-user-control-in-asp-net-c-sharp-web-page-not-working). Then, [4GuysFromRolla](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx) says this:  *Second, while ASP.NET can host both Windows User Controls and Custom Controls, it cannot host Windows Forms.*  That post, as most I saw from a quick surf, is very old. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with native ASP.NET pages and HTML. Controls on a fat client and a web page are fundamentally different.

However, you could [embed an ActiveX control on a page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752037(v=vs.85).aspx) and the ActiveX control could use your forms control. However, ActiveX controls [are only supported on Internet Explorer](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-browsers-support-activex).